# "cannot find operating system" while preparing a bootable USB stick from ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso

Tags: system-installation, usb, live-usb, system

I followed the steps in http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows and know that my USB stick is bootable.

It starts booting, but then shows an error message:

> cannot find an operating system.

I have used the same setup and installed it by double clicking the wubi.exe from Windows -- it downloaded ubuntu-12.04.3-wubi-amd64.tar.xz and installed.

So I know it is the right OS, but I am having trouble installing from my bootable USB stick.  What should I do?

Comment: Have you set USB as top priority boot device in BIOS setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that wubi.exe file was not able to connect to the internet and therefore could not download the amd64.tar.xz file.

I just downloaded the amd64.tar.xz file from the internet and pasted it into the same folder/directory as the wubi.exe file.

My USB stick got booted perfectly and Ubuntu was installed quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Linux Live](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/download) to make a pendrive bootable from windows.

Try again to make pendrive bootable by formatting it once. It should work.

Answer (score -1):

Use [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.net/) it is more user friendly IMO.

checklists -> Run unetboot in in admin mode, or disable UAC in windows.

press <kbd>F12</kbd> after bios post to get boot list and boot from USB.